# Infographic: Visualize total Increase despite procentual decrease

Tags: information-graphics, data-visualisation

I have this infographic: As you (hopefully) can see, this is about traffic increase versus shifting in different modes of transportation.

[image]

Now although the projection of car use in 2050 is decreased with 68% vs. 73%, the total traffic increases 111%. So in reallity there will be more cars on the road in 2050

Do you know any better visualizations to show that although car traffic decreases, the total volume is increasing.

This is doing already a better job than a standard pie chart, but maybe there is something even better?

Comment: No solution, just an observation: It *hugely* confuses me that the '68' bar in the lower part is longer than the '73' one above it. Maybe use absolute numbers rather than percentages?

Comment: yes it confuses me as well it's super unintuitive. removing the numbers altogether eases it. But maybe there is another solution

Comment: What if you add the percentage symbol on the areas where it fits, and **normalise according to 2017**? Meaning, the lower bar will add up to 111%. To clarify, you could add a callout 'total:  111% of 2017' to the right of the bar.

Comment: hmm. that could be a solution. I usually work in climatology where everything is based on reference years. adding numbers not relative to the reference year is a huge no-go. But maybe I should try regardles lol

Comment: The numbers don't make sense. I work with financial charts, and they would never show a 68 bigger than a 73 ... not sure what that is. If its bigger, it must look bigger. Climate sounds so relative :))

Comment: i think the problem is it reads 100% if it just reads nothing where it now says reference year its now entirely readable normal bar graph. All you need to do is scale it correctly and use rel numbers not percentage points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me you actually have 2 charts here - total traffic, and vehicle usage.

I don't know how helpful this is, but given that there are *actually* two differentiators, I was playing with a method of showing *that* rather than trying to integrate them. After all, the "total vehicles" can *never* be greater than 100%. Keeping the vehicles bars at the same length goes a long way to instant visual recognition of the differences.

[image]

Or

[image]

Comment: I agree, the point should be made about the 11% absolute traffic increase. And that's one part of the information. The other part is the percentage split in both cases, but these need to add up to 100%. I mean 68+24+4+4=100, so you can't distort math and say these add up to 111%.